# Change script directory to user's homedir in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my bash script I need to change current dir to user's home directory.

if I want to change to user's *foo* home dir, from the command line I can do:

```
cd ~foo
```

Which works fine, however when I do the same from the *script* it tells me:

```
./bar.sh: line 4: cd: ~foo: No such file or directory
```

Seams like it would be such a trivial thing, but it's not working. What's the problem here? Do I need to escape the "~" or perhaps missing quotes or something else?

**Edit**

when I say *user* I don't mean *current* user that runs the script, but in general any *other* user on the system

**Edit**

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="foo"
cd ~$user
```

if username is hardcoded like

```
cd ~foo
```

it works, but if it is in the *user* variable then it doesn't. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you want the home directory for the user foo, or the directory foo in the user's home directory?

Comment: I want home directory of user foo

Comment: What does your shebang look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about

```
cd $(getent passwd foo | cut -d: -f6)
```

and

```
USER=foo
eval cd ~$USER
```

works, too (foo is the username)

Comment: the first one (perhaps even with backticks instead of $() ) is more portable since not every shell supports cd ~USER.

Answer (score 8):

Change it to:

```
cd $HOME
```

Actually, I'm not sure why `cd ~whatever` wouldn't work.  I've just tested with a small script and it worked fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~sbright
```

I actually get the same error message that you do when the specified user does not exist on the system.  Are you sure (and yes, I know this is one of those is-it-plugged-in questions) that the user exists and has a valid home directory specified?

**Edit:**

Now that I see what you are actually doing... tilde expansion happens before variable interpolation, which is why you are getting this error.

Comment: When I mean _user_ I don't mean the current user who runs the script, but any OTHER user on the system

Comment: Could you post more of your script?

Comment: Yes user exists, I know that simply because same exact thing works from command line

Answer (score 0):

Is the script going to be run by the user? If it is you can just do:
`cd ~`

Comment: No no, script is run by root user and doing operations on _other_ users.

Comment: Bash must be interpreting the tilde and the variable in some way that we don't expect. After a wee bit of trail and error this works: USER=~foo; 
cd $USER;

Answer (score -1):

Is there some reason you can't do:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/$USER
```

Of course directories aren't in /home on all *nixes, but assuming you know what OS/distro your script is targeted for, you should be able to come up with something that works well enough.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but this /home/$USER is simply not going to work due to our configuration. Using "~" in my environment is the only feasible way to lookup the user's home.

Comment: More generally, while /home is the usual path to home directories, it is not guaranteed. I've seem /u/home and /home/user[1-9]/ and other arrangements.