# Changing to root user inside shell script

Tags: shell, su

I have a shell script which needs non-root user account to run certain commands and then change the user to root to run the rest of the script. I am using SUSE11.
I have used expect to automate the password prompt. But when I use
spawn su -
and the command gets executed, the prompt comes back with root and the rest of the script does not execute.

Eg.

```
< non-root commands>
 spawn su -
<root commands>
```

But after su - the prompt returns back with user as root.
How to execute the remaining of the script.

The sudo -S option does not help as it does not run sudo -S ifconfig command which I need to find the IP address of the machine.

I have already gone through these links but could not find a solution:
[Change script directory to user's homedir in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521226/change-script-directory-to-users-homedir-in-a-shell-script)

[Changing unix user in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493464/changing-unix-user-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: If you are using `bash`, you can create a function and pass the definition to `sudo`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269078/executing-a-bash-script-function-with-sudo

Answer (score 29):

`sudo` will work here but you need to change your script a little bit:

```
$ cat 1.sh 
id 
sudo -s <<EOF
echo Now i am root
id
echo "yes!"
EOF

$ bash 1.sh
uid=1000(igor) gid=1000(igor) groups=1000(igor),29(audio),44(video),124(fuse)
Now i am root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
yes!
```

You need to run your command in `<<EOF` block and give the block to `sudo`.

If you want, you can use `su`, of course. But you need to run it using `expect/pexpect` that will enter password for you.

But even in case you could manage to enter the password automatically (or switch it off) this construction would not work:

```
user-command
su 
root-command
```

In this case `root-command` will be executed with user, not with root privileges, because it will be executed after `su` will be finished (`su` opens a new shell, not changes uid of the current shell). You can use the same trick here of course:

```
su -c 'sh -s' <<EOF
# list of root commands
EOF
```

But now you have the same as with `sudo`.

Answer (score 13):

There is an easy way to do it without a second script. Just put this at the start of your file:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then
    sudo su -s "$0"
    exit
fi
```

Then it will automatically run itself as root. Of course, this assumes that you can `sudo su` without having to provide a password - but that's out of scope of this answer; see one of the other questions about using sudo in shell scripts for how to do that.

Comment: Be careful; `"$0"` [may not be what you think it is](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE That is interesting, but I am making the assumption here that $0 is the command to start the current process, not the path to the current file, so it's a little less fragile. Still, a good point, and very helpful link.

Comment: for password prompt just use `echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S su -c "$0"`

Comment: maybe we should add `exec` in front of `sudo` to avoid creating another subprocess.

Answer (score 6):

Short version: create a block to enclose all commands to be run as root.

For example, I created a script to run a command from a root subdirectory, the segment goes like this:

```
sudo su - <<EOF
cd rootSubFolder/subfolder
./commandtoRun
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, note that if you are changing to "root" user inside a shell script like below one, few Linux utilities like awk for data extraction or defining even a simple shell variable etc will behave weirdly.

To resolve this simply quote the whole document by using <<'EOF' in place of EOF.

```
sudo -i <<'EOF'
ls
echo "I am root now"
EOF
```

Comment: Upvoted this untested. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/947936/11154841 which says the same. I guess that this might help since I did have weird behaviour of vars using the accepted answer. I chose another workaround ([switch the permissions for the task only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72006910/11154841)) and will not make the effort to rerun it, but this seems a good try.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that would be to create a least two scripts.

The first one should call the second one with root privileges. So every command you execute in the second script would be executed as root.

For example:

**runasroot.sh**

```
sudo su-c'./scriptname.sh'
```

**scriptname.sh**

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

or whatever you need.

Comment: What if, instead of root, lets call it $USERNAME2?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but It should be sudo su -c'bash scriptname.sh'
There should be whitespace between su and -c

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that will call the script again as root passing the first argument to the new call:

```
A=$1
run_with_sudo() {
    local prompt

    prompt=$(sudo -nv 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # the current user has sudo and the password is already set
        if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
            # restart script as root
            exec sudo su - <<EOF
                "$0" "$A"
EOF
            exit
        fi
    elif echo $prompt | grep -q '^sudo:'; then
        echo "the current user has sudo but needs the password entered"
        return 1
    else
        echo "the current user has no sudo rights"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

note that "$0" [may not be what you think it is]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)